# Условный оператор в качестве индекса массива

Tags: массивы

Приведите пример языков программирования (если есть), где можно записать условный оператор в качестве индекса массива.
Например:
`a[1 < 2] = 10; // a[1] -> 10`
`a[1 > 2] = 10; // a[0] -> 10`

Comment: Кроме с++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C#

```
class Foo
{
    private int[] _bar;

    public Foo(int count = 10)
    {
        _bar = new int[count];
    }
    public int this[bool idx]
    {
        get{return idx ? _bar[0] : _bar[_bar.Length - 1];}//если true, возвращаем первый элемент, иначе последний, можете настроить собственную логику поведения
    }
    public int this[int idx]
    {
        get{ return _bar[idx];}
        set{ _bar[idx] = value;}
    }

}
```

использование:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f[0] = 47;
f[9] = 74;
f[1 < 2].Dump(); //-> 47
f[1 > 2].Dump(); //-> 74
```

Comment: хитро! ну формально правильно :-)
на яве тоже должен такой механизм работать?

Comment: нет, в Java нет перегрузки операторов

Answer (score 3):

В Паскаль/делфи

```
var a:array[boolean] of integer;
begin
  a[1>2] := 3;
  a[1<2] := 4;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых желательно вопрос уточнить. Потому что оператор в русскоязычной литературе по программированию (statement) -- это одно, а операция (operator) -- несколько иное. Если Вы имеете в виду операцию, то исходный пример некорректен. Операция в качестве индекса это

```
a[<] = 1;
a[>] = 2;
a[==] = 3;
```

Таких не знаю. Если говорить о примерах `a[1 < 2] = 1`, то мы имеем значении логического типа в качестве индекса. Там примеры языков уже приведены. Могу добавить haskell, правда с оговоркой, что в языке массивов нет, но вот реализации массивов средствами haskell такое позволяют

```
let a = array (False, True) [] :: (Array Bool Int)
```

В результате имеем пустой массив типа Array Bool Int

Если имеется в виду условное выражение (?: в C), то тут речь идёт просто о языках, где есть такие выражения и есть массивы.

Comment: немного неправильно сформулировал, но большинство поняли что я имел ввиду :)

Answer (score 1):

Помимо подавляющего большинства языков, где результат логического выражения неявно приводится к {0, 1}, можно привести пример языка R, где массив булевских переменных используется для выбора значений из массива:

```
> a <- sample(1:20, 10, T)
> a
[1]  3  1 16  3 13 12 15  4 20 20
> a[a > 10] #выбираем все элементы, которые больше 10
[1] 16 13 12 15 20 20
> a[a %% 2 == 0] #выбираем все четные элементы
[1] 16 12  4 20 20
```

Comment: в C# такое тоже возможно=)
<pre>
public IEnumerable<int> this[Func<int,bool> predicate]
{
 get{return _bar.Where(predicate);}
}
</pre>
использование:
<pre>
Foo f = new Foo();
f[a => a > 0].Dump();
f[a => a % 2 == 0].Dump();
</pre>

Answer (score -1):

В PHP можно так a['1<2']=10; a['1>2']=10

Comment: но это уже только визуально условный оператор, а на самом деле - строка.

Comment: есть в php функция eval() - выполняет строку) Пользоватся нада ей тоолько в крайних случаях из-зи соображения безопасности. Но автор задал вопрос- и данный ответ имеет право на существование